# loading files with Functions in php

Tags: php, function, include, require

```
  <?php

function index(){   
    require 'views/meta_info.php';
    require 'views/home.php';
}

index();

    ?>
```

This is i was trying to do... is this a proper method??

i tried using `include` also,

```
  <?php

function index(){   
    include 'views/meta_info.php';
    include 'views/home.php';
}

index();

    ?>
```

but its not working.. please let me know how to make this work or please tell me any alternate.

Comment: Both are proper methods. The only difference between an include and a require statement is that require will stop execution if the file is not included, and include will still keep going: http://php.net/require

Comment: Use header in file `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and what you get?

Comment: the php files must be resides in "projectfolder/view/"

Comment: And make sure the directory is correct. The can use `ini_set('include_path', ????)` to specify the root.

Comment: do you have those files in `views` directory.

Comment: have you checked by function_exists('index') ? it may possible that something is wrong with path

Comment: Sorry Guys, Its working now, i was failing to load CSS, now everything is fine.. thanks for reply ..

Answer (score 1):

You can't use defined variables in include 'views/meta_info.php';include 'views/home.php'; files. Because only valid in index function

and defined variables outside index function cannot use in index function. Because don't have function parameters.